# Android - Change a column type in SQLite database dynamically at runtime

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite

I have an application, where I am detecting the type of a particular column at run-time, on page load.  Please refer the below code:

```
public String fncCheckColumnType(String strColumnName){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String strColumnType = "";
        Cursor typeCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT typeof (" + strColumnName +") from tblUsers, null);
        typeCursor.moveToFirst();
        strColumnType = typeCursor.getString(0);
        return strColumnType;
}
```

The above method simply detects the type of column with column Name 'strColumnName'. I am getting the type of column in this case.

Now, I want to change the column type to TEXT if I am receiving INTEGER as the column type. For this, I tried the below code:

```
public String fncChangeColumnType(String strColumnName){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String newType = "";
        Cursor changeCursor = db.rawQuery("ALTER TABLE  tblUsers  MODIFY COLUMN " + strColumnName + " TEXT", null);
        if (changeCursor != null && changeCursor.moveToFirst()){
            newType = changeCursor.getString(0);
        }

        return newType;
 }
```

But while executing the 'fncChangeColumnType' method, I am getting this error, `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "MODIFY": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE tblUsers MODIFY COLUMN UserID TEXT`

NOTE: I also replaced 'MODIFY' with 'ALTER', but still getting the same error.

Please check if this is the right method to change the type dynamically.

Please respond back if someone has a solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In brief, the solution could be :-

1. **Do nothing** (i.e. take advantage of SQLite's flexibility)

   1. you could utilise CAST e.g. `CAST(mycolumn AS TEXT)` *(as used below)*
2. **Create a new table to replace the old table**.

### Explanations.

With SQLite there are limitations on what can be altered. In short you cannot change a column. Alter only allows you to either rename a table or to add a column. As per :-

[image]

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

However, with the exception of a column that is an alias of the **rowid** column

- one defined with `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` or `?? INTEGER ... PRIMARY KEY(??)` (where ?? represents a valid column name)

you can store any type of value in any type of column. e.g. consider the following (which stores an INTEGER, a REAL, a TEXT, a date that ends up being TEXT and a BLOB) :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example1_table (col1 BLOB);
INSERT INTO example1_table VALUES (1),(5.678),('fred'),(date('now')),(x'ffeeddccbbaa998877665544332211');
SELECT *, typeof(col1) FROM example1_table;
```

The result is :-

[image]

As such is there a need to change the column type at all?

If the above is insufficient then your only option is to create a new table with the new column definitions, populate it if required from the original table, and to then replace the original table with the new table ( *a) drop original and b)rename new or a) rename original, b) rename new and c) drop original*)

e.g. :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS original;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS original (mycolumn INTEGER);
INSERT INTO original VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(0);
-- The original table now exists and is populated

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtable (mycolumn TEXT); 
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT CAST(mycolumn AS TEXT) FROM original;
ALTER TABLE original RENAME TO old_original;
ALTER TABLE newtable RENAME TO original;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS old_original;
SELECT *,typeof(mycolumn) FROM original;
```

The result being :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think the sql query statement is wrong ,try

```
ALTER TABLE tblUsers MODIFY COLUMN id TYPE integer USING (id::integer);
```

instead of id use column name....

hope this helps....

EDIT:

```
"ALTER TABLE tblUsers MODIFY COLUMN "+strColumnName+" TYPE integer USING ("+strColumnName+"::integer);"
```

Comment: But you are not providing the column name at all.

Comment: isnt "strColumnName" the column name?

Comment: Yes it is, but you are not providing the column name in your line of code.

Comment: "id" is the column name here

Comment: yes replace id with strcolumnname, i edited the above ans accordingly

Comment: try using ' ' instead of " " , i also faced same problems , the rest code being perfect ,sql statements giving error .

Comment: replace alter column with modify column , as android uses sqlite & alter isnt there ......

Comment: same error -->  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "MODIFY": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE tblUsers MODIFY COLUMN UserID TYPE integer USING (UserID::integer)